# Is there any consequences to ignoring Little Paro about an incoming Raid?

Tags: ys-viii

When a new Raid is going to start Little Paro contacts you with a certain degree of urgency telling you that Castaway Village is going to be attacked and to return "if you have time". alot of the time he has done this just short of me reaching a Crystal which i could use to Fast Travel back after i deal with the raid (though normally I find this out after).

recently i was climbing up Mt Gendarme, i had just gotten back outside when Little Paro told me about the Raid and not seeing a nearby crystal i Fast Traveled back. on my return trip i found that i was a fair aways from the next Crystal.

I am wondering if there is there any consequences to ignoring Little Paro about an incoming Raid? allowing me to reach the next crystal to use as a return point

Answer (score 1):

From digging around on the internet (I have not played the game), it appears ignoring a raid will **not** gain you any reputation points, whereas beating it can grant you up to 4 (depending on the rank you get, S rank giving 4 and every rank below reducing by 1). Reputation points determine the **ending** of the game that you receive, with exact score shown below:

> True Ending – A minimum of 198 reputation points
>
> Normal ending – Between 103 and 197 reputation points
>
> Bad ending – Less than 103 reputation points

[Source](https://rpgoverload.com/ys-viii-lacrimosa-of-dana-how-to-get-the-true-ending/)

---

[The wiki also states](https://isu.fandom.com/wiki/Ys_VIII:_Lacrimosa_of_Dana#Systems) "if Adol **returns** to the village **at that time**, a raid battle will be available", suggesting that if you don't, you can never do that raid again.